# condition check to see which method to use in vue input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, onclicklistener, conditional-operator

Currently learning `vue` by making a todo list.

I wanted to be able to edit the todo items, so I added a button for edit. and upon edit the input will be a text type and edit's text will be save.

I got them working but final part where save (same button as edit) is clicked.
I tried using something like

```
  <button
    class="btn btn-sm"
    :class="editable ? 'btn-outline-success' : 'btn-outline-info'"
    @click.prevent="editable ? onSave : onEdit">{{ editable ? 'save' : 'edit' }}
  </button>
```

This actually disabled the button somehow that when I click the button the `onEdit` method does not even happen at all.

Am I doing it wrong or this is just not possible?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not calling the function in a correct way. I have done it in the code snippet below. You can check it out. I've used the same class syntax.

[Online IDE Link - Check this out - vue.js](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-ks3hn8?file=src/App.vue)

Hope It helps!

Comment: ah! Thanks, I never thought of adding `()` because usually it's not needed and quite a few tutorials keep meaning explicitly no `()` needed.  So not expecting it'll be needed in this situation :|

Answer (score 0):

Your class syntax is a bit wrong. It expects an object with classes as key and true or false as value

```
:class="{  'btn-outline-success' : editable,  'btn-outline-info' : !editable }"
```

Comment: I get what you mean, but then what I have works too though no errors